# Matplotlib, eliminate space between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm looking for a way to eliminate vertical space between my subplots. I tried using
`fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)`, but that didn't seem to do the trick.
Anyone knows a way to do it?

I'll add the code I'm using below (even though it might be a bit long), but if you want to try and run it yourselves here's a link to my github with the jupyter code and the files I'm using

https://github.com/FrancescoAzzollini/Langmuir-Waves-Analysis

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

event_start_time = dt.datetime(2002,4,25,5,56,6) # start time of the event
f2_header = 46 # 6 eV to 1113 eV 
f3_header = 51 # 200 eV to 27 keV 
f1_header = 72 # 27 keV up 
spec_header = 43

date_for_path = '25-04-2002'
path = 'Langmuir waves analysis/' + date_for_path + '/'
spec_name = 'WI_H1_WAV_23030.csv'
f2_name = 'WI_ELSP_3DP_23030.csv' # ELSP
f3_name = 'WI_EHSP_3DP_23030.csv' # EHSP
f1_name = 'WI_SFSP_3DP_23030.csv' # SFSP


def arrival_time(E):
    m = 9.1e-31
    v = np.sqrt(3.2e-16 * E/m)
    dist = 215*7e8
    t = dist/v
    return event_start_time + dt.timedelta(0,t) 


df_spec = pd.read_csv(path + spec_name, header=spec_header, skipfooter=3)
df_spec['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df_spec['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

dates_list = df_spec['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'].to_list()
x_lims_ = [dates_list[0].timestamp(), dates_list[-1].timestamp()]
x_lims = list(map(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp, x_lims_))
x_lims = mdates.date2num(x_lims)

y_lims0 = np.linspace(1075, 13825, 100)
y_lims1 = np.linspace(20, 1040, 100)
y_lims2 = np.linspace(4, 245, 100)

@plt.FuncFormatter
def fake_log(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return round(10**x) #r'$10^{%.2f}$' % (x)

df_spec = df_spec.set_index('EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ')
df_spec = df_spec[df_spec.columns[::-1]].T

df_spec0 = df_spec.iloc[353:-1, :]
df_spec1 = df_spec.iloc[95:353, :]
df_spec2 = df_spec.iloc[0:95, :]

date_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
locator = mdates.HourLocator([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(15,20), layout='compressed')

col_posit = -0.1
flare_time = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(event_start_time.timestamp() + 3600)
flare_time = mdates.date2num(flare_time)


for a in ax:
    a.set_anchor('W')

for a in ax:
    a.patch.set_facecolor('black')

im = ax[0].imshow(df_spec0, norm=colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm.inferno,
                  extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[1],  np.log10(y_lims0[0]), np.log10(y_lims0[-1])], aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax[0], pad=col_posit)

ax[0].xaxis.set(major_formatter=date_format)
ax[0].tick_params(bottom = False)
ax[0].set_xticks([])
ax[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(fake_log)
ax[0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5)) 
ax[0].set_yticks(np.log10(np.array([2000, 5000, 10000])))


im = ax[1].imshow(df_spec1, norm=colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm.inferno,
                  extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[1],  np.log10(y_lims1[0]), np.log10(y_lims1[-1])], aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax[1], pad=col_posit)

ax[1].xaxis.set(major_formatter=date_format)
ax[1].tick_params(bottom = False)
ax[1].set_xticks([])
ax[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(fake_log)
ax[1].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5)) 
ax[1].set_yticks(np.log10(np.array([20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000])))


im = ax[2].imshow(df_spec2, norm=colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm.inferno, 
                  extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[1],  np.log10(y_lims2[0]), np.log10(y_lims2[-1])], aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax[2], pad=col_posit)

ax[2].xaxis.set(major_formatter=date_format)
ax[2].tick_params(bottom = False)
ax[2].set_xticks([])
ax[2].yaxis.set_major_formatter(fake_log)
ax[2].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5)) 
ax[2].set_yticks(np.log10(np.array([10, 20, 50, 100, 200])))

#second set of images

df1 = pd.read_csv(path + f1_name, header=f1_header, skipfooter=3)
df1['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

df2 = pd.read_csv(path + f2_name, header=f2_header, skipfooter=3)
df2['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

df3 = pd.read_csv(path + f3_name, header=f3_header, skipfooter=3)
df3['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')


i1, i2, i3 = 1, 1, 1
energies1 = [27, 40, 66, 108, 181, 310, 517]
energies2 = list(reversed(list(np.array([6, 7, 9, 13, 18, 27, 41, 65, 103, 164, 264, 426, 689, 1113])*1e-3)))
energies3 = list(reversed([0.137, 0.2, 0.29, 0.43, 0.64, 0.92, 1.34, 1.95, 2.85, 4.16, 6.08, 6.87, 12.97, 18.9, 27]))

#fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10,10))
while i1 < 8 :
    ax[5].plot(df1.iloc[:, 0], df1.iloc[:, i1], c=cm.rainbow([50*i1]))
    ax[5].vlines(arrival_time(energies1[i1-1]), 0,0.3, color=cm.rainbow([50*i1]), label = str(energies1[i1-1]) + ' keV')
    ax[5].set_xlim(df3.iloc[0, 0], df3.iloc[-1, 0])
    ax[5].set_yscale("log")
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    i1 += 1

while i2 < 15 :
    ax[3].plot(df2.iloc[:, 0], df2.iloc[:, i2], c=cm.rainbow([20*i2]), label = str(round(energies2[i2-1]*1e3)) + ' eV')
    ax[3].vlines(arrival_time(energies2[i2-1]), 0,4e8, color=cm.rainbow([20*i2]))
    ax[3].set_xlim(df3.iloc[0, 0], df3.iloc[-1, 0])
    ax[3].set_yscale("log")
    i2 += 1

while i3 < 15 :
    ax[4].plot(df3.iloc[:, 0], df3.iloc[:, i3], c=cm.rainbow([20*i3]), label = str(round(energies3[i3-1]*1e3)) + ' eV')
    ax[4].vlines(arrival_time(energies3[i3-1]), 0,1e5, color=cm.rainbow([20*i3]))
    ax[4].set_xlim(df3.iloc[0, 0], df3.iloc[-1, 0])
    ax[4].set_yscale("log")
    i3 += 1

ax[0].vlines(flare_time, np.log10(y_lims0[0]), np.log10(y_lims0[-1]), 'r')
ax[1].vlines(flare_time, np.log10(y_lims1[0]), np.log10(y_lims1[-1]), 'r')
ax[2].vlines(flare_time, np.log10(y_lims2[0]), np.log10(y_lims2[-1]), 'r')
ax[4].set_ylim(None, 8e4)
ax[3].set_ylim(top=3e8)
ax[5].set_ylim(top=0.2)
ax[3].set_xticks([])
ax[4].set_xticks([])
ax[3].legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize = 11, frameon=False)
ax[4].legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize = 11, frameon=False)
ax[5].legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize = 11, frameon=False)
ax[5].set_xlabel('UT', fontsize = 20)
ax[1].set_ylabel('Frequency [kHz]', fontsize = 20)
ax[4].set_ylabel('Eletrons $cm^{-2} ster^{-1} s^{-1} eV^{-1}$', fontsize = 20)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=16)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=16)

#plt.show()
plt.savefig(path + "Spec_Plot_" + date_for_path, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Did you try without `layout='compressed'`?  Could you heavily reduce the size of your test code to a minimal reproducible example? Now there is a lot of code that's unimportant for the question.

Comment: i did, but unfortunately removing ``` layout='compressed' ``` reshapes the images and their x axis don't align anymore. Sorry for the bulk of code, I'll try to give an easier example

Comment: Usually, ```plt.tight_layout()``` works for eliminating space between subplots.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I managed to solve it this morning.
What I did was get rid of the `layout='compressed'`, as suggested by JohanC, and use `add_gridspec` and `subgridspec` to create nested subplots: two outer subplots, containing each inner 3x2 subplots. I set the subplots on the right column to be non visible with `a.set_visible(False)` and then manipulated their relative widths to make the xaxis align and get the desired result.

I updated my github repository with the new, working code.
Thanks to everyone for the help :)